# JDBC communication link failure after some time

Tags: jdbc, memory-leaks, connection-pooling

I am using JDBC with proxool connection pool to connect to mysql DB. 
I am selecting large number of rows from multiple threads and after some time i get an error saying communication link failure, Last packet sent to the server was ...ago. 
I am closing connection,statement,resultSet in every thread.
The fetching time increases gradually and the exception occurs after 5-10 minutes.
I doubt it is a memory leak, but cant find any clue.

Please let me know the possible reasons.

Thanks,
Kaka

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it may related on your Connection Timeout, try to increase it.

```
con.setConnectionTimeout(X);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. But the connection is not getting timed out. The time taken by select statement to fetch almost the same amount of data is increasing gradually. It starts with 30 secs and after 5 mins it crosses 100 seconds, so it has to be something related to memory leak or filled buffers etc. But not able to figure it out. Any such past experience?
Thanks,
Kaka

Comment: Found that its a memory leak due to Executor service futures.Nothing related to DB