# JDBC Communication Link Failure

Tags: jdbc, connection

I have got a java program which is waiting for some input to insert the data to my database. The program works just fine, but after a like 30 minutes of idle and then trying to insert some data again I get a communication link failure. I guess I get this failure because the connection gets a reset. other stackoverflow threads suggest to adjust my MySQL settings, but this is not how I want to solve this problem.

Before executing any SQL i tried:

```
if (connection == null || connection.isClosed()) {
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://www.mysql.url?autoReconnect=true", "user", "pwd");
}
```

which is not working, connection is not closed when receiving a communication link failure. Then I tried using dbcp library from apache using this tutorial: [link](http://www.javatips.net/blog/dbcp-connection-pooling-example). By using this library I do not get communication link failures but instead after calling datasource.getConnection() like 3 times it is not responding (seems like a deadlook but I could not find any solutions on the internet).

Is there a way to check for communication link failure before executing SQL? Because I would really prefer to use native jdbc as I just execute a simple insert statement every 10 min - 10 hours

Comment: If you proces a statement from a single session once every 10 minutes to 10 hours, I don't see a problem with acquiring the connection each time before the insert and closing it after that. Simple try it and see if you have less problems:)

Comment: That's true.. I just wondered if there could be a better way since getting a new connection sometimes takes up to 10 seconds and does not seem to be the right solution for me. But I'll take it since it seems there is no solution :D Ty

Comment: The alternative (also frequently used) is to perform every couple of minutes a select from a dummy table to see if the connection is fine. If not, perform re-connect.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JDBC communication link failure after some time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350576/jdbc-communication-link-failure-after-some-time)